# How can I apply style to a div based on condition in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf, conditional-operator

I have a `<div>` block which I need to set to `display:none` or `display:block` based on the condition. The html looks like this,

```
<div style="display:none;"> 
    //some html block content
</div>
```

I've tried the following code in thymeleaf,

```
<div th:style="${condition} == 'MATCH' ? display:block : display:none"> 
    //some html block content
</div>
```

But the above expression is not working. throws `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression:` error message.

I can do `th:classappend` to set some class and make this work but want to know if elvis/ternary operator will support on thymeleaf `th:style` tag.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Solved it while posting the question,

```
th:style="${condition ? 'display:block' : 'display:none'}" >
```

would produce the necessary conditional style. If condition is true display is set to block and none if condition is false.

For admin,

```
th:style="${role == 'ADMIN' ? 'display:block' : 'display:none'}" >
```

the style is set to `display:block` and for other roles the block is not displayed.

Comment: Correction: `th:style="${condition ? 'style1' : 'style2'}"`

Comment: You can use `th:styleappend` if you want to keep your existing styles

Answer (score 2):

In simple case it could be written as

```
<div th:style="${filed==null ? 'opacity:.3'}">
```