# JQuery : Style all select elements to italic only if the selected element is the first one (placeholder)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-select

I am trying to style placeholders differently with JQuery.  I am able to do it one element at a time rather easily like so :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    var cabinetFilter = document.getElementById("cabinetFilter");
    var value = cabinetFilter.options[cabinetFilter.selectedIndex].value;

    if (value == "") {
      $(cabinetFilter).css('font-style', 'italic');
      $(cabinetFilter).css('color', '#636c72');
      $(cabinetFilter).children().css('font-style', 'normal');
    } else {
      $(cabinetFilter).css('font-style', 'normal');
      $(cabinetFilter).css('color', 'black');
      $(cabinetFilter).children().css('font-style', 'normal');
    }
  }
);
</script>
```

That is fine for just one select element but i have pages with 3 or 4.  I know you can target all selects using something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('select').css('font-style', 'italic');
  }
);
</script>
```

The select element in question looks like this :

```
<select class="form-control" id="cabinetFilter" name="cabinetFilter" th:value="${cabinetFilter}"
                                            onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                            <option value="">Search Cabinet</option>
                                            <option th:each="cabinet : ${cabinets}" th:value="${cabinet.id}" 
                                                th:text="${cabinet.toString()}" th:selected="${cabinet.id == cabinetFilter}">
                                                </option>
                                        </select>
```

How would i adapt the second example and tell it to only apply the style if the first element is selected?

Comment: Please add (minimal)HTML. Also, please define 'selected'? A select element itself is not selected at all, only the options in it are. Do you  mean that, or are you looking for the focused one?

Comment: Added an example of one of the select components.  My goal is to style the text of the select input only if the first option in the list is selected, AKA the placeholder with no value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per you first example and the requirment, I assume you want to iterate on number of `select` DOM elements and check if a value is selected or not.

You can do it with [each loop](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
function checkSelectElements()
{
    $('select').each(function (index, value){
      if($(this).val()===""){ 
        $(this).css('font-style', 'italic');
        $(this).css('color', '#636c72');
        $(this).children().css('font-style', 'normal');   
      }
      else
      {
        $(this).css('font-style', 'normal');
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
        $(this).children().css('font-style', 'normal');    
      }
  });
}
```

Here is [a working example](https://codepen.io/Alon_A/pen/EJMvyo?editors=1111).

Comment: Thank you internet friend!  Nailed it!

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#introducing-thymeleaf), if so, then you can also use [conditional styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165486/how-can-i-apply-style-to-a-div-based-on-condition-in-thymeleaf), without needing any further JavaScript.

Change your select by adding `th:style="${cabinetFilter==''} ? 'font-style:italic' : 'font-style:normal'"` (I am assuming here that your default value is an empty string, if it is NULL you should check for `${cabinetFilter==NULL}`.

```html
<select class="form-control" id="cabinetFilter" name="cabinetFilter" onchange="this.form.submit()"
    th:value="${cabinetFilter}" 
    th:style="${cabinetFilter==''} ? 'font-style:italic' : 'font-style:normal'" >
        <option value="">Search Cabinet</option>
        <option 
            th:each="cabinet : ${cabinets}" 
            th:value="${cabinet.id}" 
            th:text="${cabinet.toString()}" 
            th:selected="${cabinet.id == cabinetFilter}">
        </option>
</select>
```

Don't forget to add a bit of css to put the option texts back to non-italic:

```html
<style>
    select > option{
        font-style: normal;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: That is a good idea indeed however would be a bit tedious to change all of them at this point (i have something like 30 pages with a similar form).  I will definitely keep this in mind though, i had not thought of doing it with thymeleaf!

Comment: Yes, I can see it can be a lot of work if you have to do it manually. You could maybe try search and replace over all 30 files using a regular expression? something like search for: /<select(.+?)(th:style="\${(.+?)}")(.+?)>/ and replace with <select${1}${2} th:style="\${${3}==''} ? 'font-style:italic' : 'font-style:normal'" ${4}>? (something like this will work in Sublime).

Comment: At this point i prefer the jQeury approach because it will work for an entire HTML file even if it has 5 of these select components with a simple copy pasting of a script at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to change when someone changes an option from the select statement. What you could do is:

```
// When a select statement changes check if the option selected has a value of ""
// If so give it an italic style. If not, set it to normal
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).css({'font-style':'italic'});
    } else {
        $(this).css({'font-style':'italic'});
    }
});
```

If you want it from page load I recommend Alon Adler's answer.

Comment: so, i tried this and it works BUT the problem is each select has a change listener that submits the form they are part of so the page reloads.  This would work otherwise.  I can see the style change but it's back to normal when the page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a CSS class for any styling. It's kind of what "style sheets" are made for. Then, just have a function that removes the class from every select, then adds it back to those that have the first option selected. (you could use `:first-child` instead of `[value=""]` if needed.

```js
function updateSelects() {
  $('select').removeClass('unselected');
  $('select').has('option[value=""]:selected').addClass('unselected');
}
$('select').on('change', updateSelects);
updateSelects();
```

```css
.unselected {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #636c72;
}

.unselected option {
  font-style: normal;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">Select something</option>
  <option value="1">Something</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="">Select something</option>
  <option value="1">Something</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="">Select something</option>
  <option value="1">Something</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="">Select something</option>
  <option value="1">Something</option>
</select>
```